# How to speed up registration of microservices in spring cloud eureka?

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, microservices, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I have a spring-cloud-eureka application, respectively, I have one eureka-server service, the second gateway, the third client service.

After starting all the services, the connection between them occurs after 30-40 seconds, although eureka registers gateway and client almost immediately, but getting through gateway to client -> gateway:port/client/controller is only possible after a while...

How using kafka, to arrange a quick connection between this sstructur (not communication between services) but the interaction of eureka with microservices?

Is there such a possibility at all, I did not find even an example anywhere?

Comment: There is no way to use Kafka for communication with eureka. There are 30 second windows on each eureka client and the eureka server to accommodate large deployments of thousands of services and is eventually consistent. If you only have a few instances you might consider spring cloud consul

Comment: @spencergibb Thank you very much for the answer, you made it clear that this is not possible at the moment, I will not have to spend time looking for a solution!

Comment: Kafka isn't very useful for p2p connections like this anyway. Consul or Raft based protocols or Zookeeper are better